# (homebrew.mxcl.mysql[2274]): Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error = 2: No such file or directory

Tags: homebrew, mysql

If I run console on my mac and go to the system.log I see that system,log is getting flooded with this error

```
Oct 31 15:57:59 abhisheks-mbp com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql[2185]): Service could not initialize: Unable to set current working directory. error = 2: No such file or directory, path = /usr/local/var/mysql: 17A405: xpcproxy + 11040 [1403][43FABD4F-8081-3087-91BC-95B588688D55]: 0x2
Oct 31 15:57:59 abhisheks-mbp com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (homebrew.mxcl.mysql): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
Oct 31 15:58:03 abhisheks-mbp com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.preference.displays.MirrorDisplays): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

I had installed mysql using homebrew many months ago. but I had removed it I don't know why its still trying to run it.

I tried to remove mysql

```
~ > brew uninstall mysql
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/mysql
```

But still i see messages pouring in.

Answer (score 10):

You probably enabled the MySQL launch agent with `brew services start mysql` in the past and forgot to disable the brew service (before uninstalling mysql) which would remove the plist.

So unload and remove the agent from the launchd database manually with:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
launchctl remove ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Then remove the file:

```
rm ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

If you did a custom install of the plist, the file homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist may reside in /Library/LaunchAgents. Use the same commands then but adjust the paths above and prepend `sudo`.

Answer (score -1):

Got to Key Access App. It's a built in App through Finder or Launchpad, usually found in the compiled folder that says "Other." delete any keys or certificates that reference the error message output.

For example, if you see `com.apple.xpc.mysql` or `com.homebrew.mxcl.mysql` delete it.